# How to compare today's date with Date of Excel column to display today's entered data in C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, oledb

I need to compare today's date with dates in Excel so that it displays all data entered today in DataGridView. I have tried many code iterations but continue to receive errors and some do not show required result. Here is the code:

```
 private void todayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int day = todaysDate.Day ;
        int month =todaysDate.Month;
        MessageBox.Show("Month" + month+ "Date" + day, "abc", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        int year = todaysDate.Year;

        String name = "Sheet1";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
       OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$] WHERE Date CONTAINS " + day + "AND Date CONTAINS " + month +
            "AND Date CONTAINS " + year, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED
Use query with parameters instead of injecting value into the string. This is working fine for me:

```
OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$] WHERE Date = @date");
oconn.Connection = connection;
try
{
    oconn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: Its giving error " Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: It is not giving any output

Comment: @Tasneem this is working for me, `data`  is getting correct rows. Check your excel file. Do you have records with today's date?

Comment: Yes I have just added record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149275/discussion-between-tasneem-and-samvel-petrosov).